# Inserting a string with sed

Tags: sed

I need help to find and insert a string of characters using `sed`:

Before:

```
"AdminHostName" value=""
```

After:

```
"AdminHostName" value="my-text"
```

Answer (score 3):

If you simply want to replace the empty `value`:

```
sed 's/value=""/value="my-text"/'
```

With the rather vague description of your problem, the following also works:

```
sed 's/""/"my-text"/'
```